# How to require a plugin in a phonegap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to make [this](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeDemo) example of [phonegap barcode scanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) plugin work. I've replaces all files in `www` folder, and also I've installed the plugin using CLI command

```
phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
```

but pressing scan button, only the `console.log('scanning')` command in line 55 of index.js works. my questions are:

1. Does `cordova` in requirement in line 57 of index.js point to root of project (cause I don't have such a folder)?

   `var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");`
2. Does barcodescanner.js file ship automatically (cause it's not it the example repo, and I can see it in plugins directory)?
3. After installation by CLI, the line

   `<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner"/>`

was not in `config.xml`. Do I need to add it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this example works correctly cause all files of a complete project are not supplied in repository. I prefer to give a more detail, to cover the issue completely.

Let's check a few points you need to take care of for installing plugins:

1. Add platforms before installing plugin
2. Installing plugins using CLI is proffered
3. Plugins **usually** only work on real device as installed app, not on you browser nor in Phonegap scanner.
4. You don't need to add any line of code to config.xml and cordova will do it to the config inside `platforms/{os}` folder *(The 3rd question)*.

Some plugins don't need any further manual file transfers of and kind of linking scripts to HTML pages, but some need. the `barcodeScanner` is one of those needing to:

1. Do not link `barcodescanner.js` to the `index.html` file `Cordova` will do it automatically *(The 1st question)*.
2. Every plugin has a `plugin.xml` file. looking through it, there is `js-module` element which has at least one `clobbers` element. this element has a target attribute which indicated the global module that will be available globally. in this case, check if `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner` is available **by generating a debug apk or api file**.
3. Normally you do not need to make requirements in your own code, because the build process will wrap the plugin in a `cordova.require` closure. about this plugin, simply use:

   `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function (result) {}, function (error) {});`

Answer (score 2):

You can install plugin by following ways:

1 - Add "**phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner**" in your gruntFile plugin list

2 - cd phonegap directory and run "**sudo phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner**".

After that you should be able to use  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(success, failure);

In this case you don't need to change anything manually, this will be automated.

Hope this helps you!

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you so much. your answer is correct. but I marked another answer as it is in more detail and may help other.